# Insert default value in view without creating table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, syntax, create-view

I have to create a view in SQL that has a set of default values without creating any tables, and I don't know if it is possible or not? Maybe something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW PersonalView 
AS 
    SELECT * 
    FROM (VALUES('Sara', 'Moradi', '22'))
```

Comment: Why isn't what you have working? Is it purely due to the lack of aliases?

Answer (score 2):

It is almost correct. You need to add aliases:

```
CREATE VIEW PersonalView 
AS 
SELECT * FROM ( VALUES ('Sara', 'Moradi', '22')) s(fist_name, last_name, age);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ecb6717db2d80e80b56c8ca2121de225)**

Answer (score 1):

In SQL-Server you can write a query without a `from` clause, but note you'll need to give the literals column names. E.g.:

```
CREATE VIEW PersonalView AS SELECT 'Sara' AS name, 'Moradi' AS last_name, '22' AS age
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variant you can use is

```
CREATE VIEW PersonalView (first_name, last_name, age)
AS
  SELECT 'Sara', 'Moradi', 22
```